# Adding rows in Excel with VBA code or keep lRow static

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form I am entering data with.

I need to "add" a row in Excel via VBA code and keep my `lRow`.

I would love to keep the adding rows to the bottom of the sheet but I have a formula that reference a cell and if I add to it, the formula will return bad data.

I need to add a row and keep the `lrow` or make the formula change as the row gets added to the end.

My adding row to the end of the data table is:

```
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
```

and my formula row is

```
.Cells(lRow, 21).Value = "=IF(A2<"" "",A2&TEXT(D2,""mmddyy""),"""")"
```

As I add data the formula returns bad data due to its static and the added row is does not referance `A2` anymore but `B2` ...and so on.

How can I add a row and keep `lRow` in my code working, or how to make the formula work as I add a new line, it indexes to the next line and not static anymore?

Thanks

Comment: Why would it reference B2 when you add a new row? Do you mean a new column? It's not clear what you are trying to do here with just the two little snippets of code. I believe, also, that instead of `.value` for the cell range you may want `.formula` instead.

Comment: No I am adding new rows. Need to add rows just because that is how the original sheet was set up. As far as referencing B2, I need to otherwise the VBA code as it stands now is static and will always reference A2 which is not right, it needs to move with the adding of the new line if I append it as it is now, otherwise I need to insert new row and move old rows down 1 line, and yet keep the lRow description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `.Formula` not `.Value`

And you can make the row reference variable based on `lrow`

```
.Cells(lRow, 21).Formula= "=IF(A" & lrow & "<"" "",A" & lrow & "&TEXT(D" & lrow & ",""mmddyy""),"""")"
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I needed. Your a big help, Thanks a million

Comment: @pmk please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.